# Obtener el último registro en una consulta SQL de acuerdo a la fecha

Tags: sql

Tengo una tabla que tiene estas columnas,`compra`, `serial y`fecha`.
Necesito sacar los datos de`compra`y`serial`de acuerdo a la última`fecha
`he intentado hacerlo mediante este`query`:

```
SELECT compra,serial FROM warehouse where  MAX(fecha);
```

Pero me manda este error:

> group function is not allowed here

No necesito obtener la información mediante algún id o algo parecido, solo la última compra y serial de acuerdo a la fecha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias hacer un select dentro de tu where:

```
 SELECT w.compra,w.serial FROM warehouse w 
 WHERE w.fecha = (SELECT MAX(w.fecha) from warehouse)
```

Comment: en el max se te fue el `w.`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT compra,serial 
FROM warehouse 
where fecha = (SELECT MAX(fecha) 
FROM warehouse);
```

> Prueba así pues no es válido una función de agregación directamente con un where, mejor una una subconsulta donde indiques que la fecha sea igual y dentro de los paréntesis metes la selección de la fecha mayor.

O puedes meter la subquery dentro de una **CTE** (si tu gestor soporta dicha característica) quedando así

```
WITH MaxDate AS (
    SELECT id, compra, serial FROM warehouse WHERE fecha = (SELECT MAX(fecha)FROM warehouse)
)
```

Posterior haces el `SELECT` final al alias que creaste llamado `MaxDate` quedando todo tu código de este modo

```
WITH MaxDate AS (
    SELECT id, compra, serial FROM warehouse WHERE fecha = (SELECT MAX(fecha)FROM warehouse)
)
SELECT id, compra, serial FROM MaxDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

Saludos te sugiero realizar lo siguiente:

```
SELECT campo1, campo2 FROM miTabla
WHERE fecha IN (SELECT max(fecha) FROM miTabla)
```

Te sugiero revisar lo siguiente: [Max date](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/max-date.php)